# Displaying a custom error from SSRS Report Manager for rsProcessingAborted

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services, designing reports with Report Builder 3.0 and viewing them through Report Manager (`http://host/Reports/`, not `http://host/reportserver/`).

I have a large number of reports built and accessed this way, reading data from a database which is refreshed every hour. The refresh process takes a few minutes and is a simple ETL C# script I wrote to (for each table) delete all matching rows and insert new data (inside a Transaction). It might be this part of the process I need to change, so I have tagged this question with SQL Server 2008 R2.

My issue is that **whenever the import and SSRS report execution run simultaneously, I get an rsProcessingAborted error**. It looks like processing aborts if the underlying data changes while it is executing. One of my reports is very complicated takes several minutes to run, so I see this error a lot and generally don't see it at all on the other reports.

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset xxx. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
```

These reports need to be shared with users who will not want to see the error. Is there any way I can

- make my import script and the SSRS execution "atomic" so the report is able to run anyway
- customise the rsProcessingAborted error shown in Report Manager so that the user is shown a message like "The data behind this report is being refreshed. Please try again in 5 minutes." - still irritating, but nicer than the error above...

Answer (score 0):

Use "NOLOCK" table hint in your report.

```
For Example:

SELECT [LastName] FROM [dbo].[AuditLog] WITH (NOLOCK)
```